# Socket programming for avr

Tags: sockets, avr, ethernet, atmel

I am in a dilemma that whether i can use Ethernet chip with ATmega 16 for performing socket programming or not?

I actually want to send the real time position signals over the internet to the server using client server model. But will the ATmega 16 be able to process such high data using socket programming? I will be performing socket programming in c just a basic one.

Comment: Position of what?  Snail on garden path?  Tip of turbine blade?  What 'high data'?

Comment: Real time positions of public transports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot implement a useful application with TCP socket connections in 1k RAM. So you should look for an Ethernet controller with integrated TPC/IP stack, like the WIZnet W5100.

If wireless is OK, you may also look out for GPRS/UMTS or WLAN modules with integrated TCP/IP stack. They are much more common than their cable-based counterparts.